# Как отследить инициатора события submit из обработчика в javascript (на стороне клиента, без отправки формы)?

Tags: javascript, события, submit

В форме используются несколько кнопок отправки с разными formaction. При нажатии кнопки возникает событие submit. Возможно ли из обработчика события (на стороне клиента, без отправки формы) выяснить, какая кнопка была нажата?

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var formaction = '?';
  console.log(formaction);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <button formaction="1">1</button>
  <button formaction="2">2</button>
</form>
```

**UPD. Вопрос уточнен, т.к. был помечен как дубль.**

**UPD. Протестировал следующие варианты:**

```
event.target - <form>
event.srcElement - <form>
event.currentTarget - <form>
event.originalTarget - undefined (FF <form>)
document.activeElement - <button> (Safari <body>)
event.explicitOriginalTarget - undefined (FF <button>)
```

Comment: там же в ответе есть пример с только клиентской частью

Comment: @Igor, думаешь ответ будет отличаться от дубликата? :-)

Comment: @Grundy хотелось бы

Comment: @Igor, похоже [за 8 лет](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2066162/2881286) ничего не поменялось.

Answer (score -1):

У кнопок поставить `type="button"` и они не будет срабатывать как submit формы, дальше на них повесить события и тут уже варианты. Либо менять по клику action у формы и ее уже сабмитить, либо сразу отправлять ajax submit формы.